# Xampp starts SQL than shuts down unexpectedly. No solution seems to work

Tags: xampp, mariadb

so I wanted to start my SQL today and after I press on start I get this Message:

```
13:48:29  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:48:29  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:48:29  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:48:29  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:48:29  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:48:29  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
13:48:29  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I checked the error_log file and this inside.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 5299770; transaction id 988
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200625 13:48:27
2020-06-25 13:48:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I already tried these solutions to fix the problem:

- Nothing else is blocking the port. Not Skype not anything.
- Deleted the ibtmp1 file and ib_... log files and restarted the Server.
- Changed the port from 3306 to 3307.
- Changed max_allowed_packet from 1M to 128M
- End mysql task in task manager (This does not work because I have no such task running)

This is the third time this is happening. The only way I can get it to work again if I reinstall xampp. But it takes like 30 min to connect everything again and import my tables again. Also I have to constantly export my tables so I dont loose any changes.
Is there anything else i can try?

Comment: Did you look at the Windows Event Viewer. There is normally some very good info there to help you debug

Comment: Damn there are a lot of Errors for MariaDB. One of them gives me this msg: Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593

Comment: Did you set up a Master / Slave relationship?

Comment: I did not. Also this error started happening like 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Are you sure mariadb is not picking up a my.ini from somewhere else on your system.

Comment: I searched my whole c/ folder but I found nothing else.

Comment: So does you my.ini try to setup a Master/Slave?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what the hell is going on. I have never even thought about setting up a master/slave connection. I didnt even touch the my.ini file. I have no idea where this is coming from. I have been using xammp for Months now and there was never a Problem. The only thing i could think of is that one of my friends from college I am doing this project with started coming over and we did stuff together. He also has xammp on his pc with thr port 3306 to sql. He is on my network. So i thought he blocks my port and i cant see it on my computer. But I dont konw if thats even possible.

Comment: 2 different PC's will not block each other, XAMPP has everything on the single PC and unless you attempt to go Off Piste so to speak and access a MySQL on another IP (which is fine) the 2 of you should not interfer with each other

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. Well im gonna reinstall it once again and leave my pc running for as long as we are done with this project :D.